# I'm struggling to remove this error from my function, when I try to test my code with the parameters

Tags: python

I'm struggling to remove this error from my function, when I try to test my code with the parameters listed below in the "**the errors I'm getting**" list

Can someone please help me I've been trying to fix this error and couldn't solve it?

I have listed below:

1. The number.txt file that we have to work on for this code
2. the errors I'm getting
3. my code
4. the sample testing

so my question is clear to understand.

**Work with the customers.txt file in this question.**

```
12345,Tom,Black,300.00,1998-01-30
23456,Alice,Smith,1200.50,1998-02-20
14567,Jane,White,900.00,1998-07-01
43564,Weilin,Zhao,450.25,1998-01-03
45432,Bina,Mehta,278.95,1998-03-21
```

**the errors I'm getting**

```
Test various parameters: '['customers file variable', '12345']'
ERROR:
Expected: ['12345', 'Tom', 'Black', '300.00', '1998-01-30']
Test various parameters: '['customers file variable', '45432']'
ERROR:
Expected: ['45432', 'Bina', 'Mehta', '278.95', '1998-03-21']
```

```
def customer_by_id(fh, id_number):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Find the record for a given ID in a sequential file.
    Use: result = customer_by_id(fh, id_number)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        fh - file to search (file handle - already open for reading)
        id_number - the id_number to match (str)
    Returns:
        result - the record with id_number if it exists,
            an empty list otherwise (list)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    num = fh.read().split("\id_number")
    if int(id_number) < len(num):
        result = int(num[id_number]).strip().split(",")
    else:
        result = []
    print(result)
```

**Sample testing:**

```
Find customer by id_number
Enter an ID: 23456
['23456', 'Alice', 'Smith', '1200.50', '1998-02-20']
----
Find customer by id_number
Enter an ID: 99999
[]
```

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look at the `csv` module. More info here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: on `if id_number < len(num)` the variable `id_number ` seems to be a string, not a number, try comething like  `int(id_number )` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not allowed to use CSV because we still haven't gotten there in the course.

Comment: note that the operator `<` works for string, just not compare a string with a  numeric variable

Comment: I have updated my code with your request and got different errors. I added the new errors to my question so you can see them clearly.

Comment: I think you sohuld do the same for `result = num[id_number].strip().split(",")` (use `int()` again), also , could you `print(result)`  at the end? so that we can see what is happening with the output. Note that there is no interpreter Error, it's your testing function telling you that the result is not the expected

Comment: i added your suggestions once again, but I still got the same errors idk why?

Answer (score 2):

First, in your code, `.split("\id_number")` is causing a problem. It looks for the *string* `\id_number` in the text file, which is nonexistent. Therefore this results in a list with a single element, the latter being the whole text.

And then the `if` clause does not make sense, to be blunt. The left hand side is, e.g., integer `12345` representing the customer id. The right hand side, on the other hand, is *the number of elements* of the list, i.e., 1. Syntactically correct, but semantically wrong.

So when you look at this, the LHS is almost always a big number, say 12345, whereas the RHS is 1. This `if` clause, therefore, is never going to be executed. Instead, `else` part is reached, resulting in an empty list.

Here's my suggestion without using csv.

```py
def customer_by_id(fh, id_number):
    records = f.read().splitlines()
    records = [record.split(",") for record in records]
    for record in records:
        if record[0] == id_number:
            return record
    return []

with open("customers.txt", "r") as f:
    print(customer_by_id(f, "23456"))
```

At the first line of the function definition, `records` is a list containing each lines of customers.txt. So it would look like

```
['23456,Alice,Smith,1200.50,1998-02-20', '14567,Jane,White,900.00,1998-07-01', ...]
```

Note that each element of the list is just a string.

The second line now converts each string to a list using `split()`. Now the `records` is a list of lists, i.e., each element of `records` is again a list. Now it looks like

```
[['23456', 'Alice', 'Smith', '1200.50', '1998-02-20'], ['14567', 'Jane', 'White', '900.00', '1998-07-01'], ... ]
```

Next, the for loop iterates over these sub-lists and compares the first element (of the sub-list) to the `id_number`. If they match, return the sub-list (ending the function). Otherwise, continue the iteration. When none of them matches to `id_number`, `return []` is reached.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to print the list of information:

```
def customer_by_id(fh, id_number):
    
    with open(fh, "r") as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            if line.startswith(str(id_number)):
                customer = line.strip().split(",")
    
    if not customer:
        customer = []

    return customer


while True:
    print("Find customer by id_number")
    id = input("Enter an ID: ")
    print(customer_by_id("customers.txt", id))
    print("---")
```

This will run until you either close the program or use the KeyboardInterrupt.